# Bridge between Rx & Coroutines

Tags: rx-java, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

Im trying out a kotlin multiplatform project & migrating some network calls in our app. However, I do not want to change application layer yet (which is heavily dependent on RxJava). So, in our new KMP library, I want to return Single/Observable from the API.

How can i bridge between coroutines & RxJava. Im trying to play around with https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/reactive/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2/README.md library, but don't see proper examples/documentation.

Comment: Take a look at Reaktive. There is coroutine an RX interop. https://github.com/badoo/Reaktive

Comment: Thanks so much for responding Kevin. I will check this out right away.